# Exel crashing on load of previously fine .xlsm sheet

Tags: excel, office365

Has anyone had this problem - and preferably solved it ;) - in the last 4-6 weeks or so?

I have a .xlsm workbook which has not been changed and has worked fine for 8 years but suddenly it won't load unless I load a very simple workbook first.  I get the splash screen, then it loads to about 50%-60% and then I get a message saying "Excel has stopped working".  Total shutdown and then it tries to "repair" the file until it gets bored.

After loading a random .xlsm file I can then start it ok - it's a bit tedious.  It doesn't get as far as executing any code before it crashes.

Is this something that someone knows about?

Comment: If it's 8 years old it's probably become corrupted. Best copy the data and code into a clean workbook.

Comment: Thanks Absinthe.  I did that and it worked - not without difficulty, it's a heck of a lot of sheets, modules and forms!

Comment: Glad it helped. Corruption is a risk with older workbooks. To store data long term Access is best.